# Angular service class unit test failing with can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Let me first preface this by stating I'm new to Angular and jasmine/karma unit tests.  I'm trying to write a simple test for a service class.  The test is failing with:

*Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BlahBlahService: (?).*

This is the service class:

```
export abstract class BlahBlahService extends BehaviorSubject<GridDataResult>
```

This is what the service constructor looks like:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super(null);    
}
```

This is my test:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ProductivityStatsService } from './blah-blah.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from "@angular/common/http/testing";

describe('BlahBlahService', () => {
   let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
   let service: BlahBlahService;

   beforeEach(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
       providers: [BlahBlahService]
     });

     httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
     service = TestBed.get(BlahBlahService);
   });  

   it('should work', () => {
     expect(service).toBeTruthy();
   });

 });
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your `BlahBlahService` is abstract. I don't think you can define a provider that is abstract..

Comment: Try changing `TestBed.get` to `getTestBed().get`

Comment: That must be it!  I'm able to run the same test against the derived class.  Thanks!